# Pluginlib, roscpp and catkin

Tags: ros, roscpp, pluginlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm working on a transport plugin system in roscpp and I can't find out how to link roscpp directly with pluginlib. I'd like ros::init to load the transport plugins dynamically.

roscpp is built currently with catkin, and it seems like pluginlib is not providing the information that catkin is looking for. At least this is my sketchy understanding.

Would anyone have hints on how to achieve that?
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35584/pluginlib,-roscpp-and-catkin/) by [Cedric](https://answers.ros.org/users/66/cedric/) on ROS Answers with karma: 129 on 2012-06-04

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

pluginlib is currently still based on the rosmake-buildsystem (called dry). rospp has already been migrated to the new buildsystem catkin (called wet). Dependencies are only allowed in one direction - from dry to wet (for backward compatibility).

Therefore pluginlib needs to be catkinized to be a dependency of roscpp. Please find a patch attached to the following ticket: https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5463

Currently we are preparing to release a polished and better catkin version of the core packages. As soon as that has been pushed to public we will also release an updated pluginlib package. But since the changes to the ROS system are big we try to land them in sequence.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2012-06-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0